# Inspecting Parameter Names from Annotation Processor

Tags: annotation-processing

From  [ExecutableType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/ExecutableType.html) we can inspect the types of parameters using  [getParameterTypes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/ExecutableType.html#getParameterTypes()). However, I cannot find a mechanism to inspect the parameter names.

I understand that in <= Java 7 the parameter names are not retained in the bytecode. However, I would still expect to be able to access the argument names `arg0`, `arg1`.

If the compiler is a Java 8 compiler running with the `-parameters` flag I would expect to get the original parameter names from the source code.

Is there a mechanism that I am overlooking? It seems strange that we are able to query this using the reflection API using [Parameter.getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getName--) if we are not capable of retrieving this information whilst annotation processing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ExecutableType, use [ExecutableElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html). From this you can get it's parameters which should all have names.  You can convert using [Types.asElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#asElement(javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror)).

Comment: Event with the ExecutableElement the type names are always returned as "arg0", …

Comment: Sorry, late to respond to this comment. The `arg0`, `arg1`, etc names are addressed in the question -- if you are building with Java 7 or earlier, or Java 8 w/o the `-parameters` flag, then parameter names are not stored in the bytecode. In this case they show up as `arg0`, `arg1`, etc.